# Shopify Liquid capture settings not outputting for some reason

Tags: html, json, schema, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to get and display some theme settings which gets the site name and applies to end which i have setup in the schema but cant get it to display the settings.

In the promo_header.liquid snippet file i have:

```
{% capture promo_header_text_1 %} locale_promo_1_text_{{ shop.name }} {% endcapture %}
{% capture promo_header_url_1 %} locale_promo_1_url_{{ shop.name }} {% endcapture %}
{% capture promo_header_text_2 %} locale_promo_2_text_{{ shop.name }} {% endcapture %}
{% capture promo_header_url_2 %} locale_promo_2_url_{{ shop.name }} {% endcapture %}

<p>
  {% if settings[promo_header_text_1] %}
     <a href="{{ settings[promo_header_url_1] }}">{{ settings[promo_header_text_1] }}</a>
  {% endif %}
  {% if settings[promo_header_text_2] %}
     <span>/</span><a href="{{ settings[promo_header_url_2] }}">{{ settings[promo_header_text_2] }}</a>
  {% endif %}
</p>
```

I have also tried to output using just for example

```
{{ settings.promo_header_text_1 }}
```

But not displaying anything either... when i debug and display for example

```
{{ promo_header_text_1 }}
```

It does return

```
locale_promo_1_text_website-test2
```

Which is correct and in the schema settings file (example based on that one above it is matching and is set in theme customisation)

```
 {
    "type": "text",
    "id": "locale_promo_1_text_website-test2",
    "label": "Promo 1 Text",
    "default": "FREE US SHIPPING OVER $35"
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmmm why would you make a negative mark on this when the question is very much valid, well explained, code provided and also attempted different methods to resolve with debugging.

Comment: You're adding a blank space everywhere at the start and end of capture. Remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that might come across the same issue here is the solution I got working:

```
{% assign promo_header_text_1 = 'locale_promo_1_text_' | append:shop.name %}
```

and to output

```
{{ settings[promo_header_text_1] }}
```